# Replace list item with corresponding dictionary value

Tags: python

My dictionary is

```
{'apple': '2', 'banana': '3', 'pear': '1', 'peach': '1'}
```

And my list is

```
['banana', 'apple', 'pear', 'apple banana']
```

How would I make a new list replacing the list values with the dictionary values?
This is what the new list should be.

```
['3', '2', '1', '5']
```

And how would I add all the values up to get a new list with the numbers added inside like this

```
['11']
```

I have tried:

```
result = map(dictionary.get, l)
print(list(result))
```

But this gives the wrong answer: `['3', '2', '1', None]`

Comment: You loop over each value in the list and then lookup that value in the dictionary to get its new value...

Comment: Could you possibly paste a code in? I am asking how to do it for a reason... That reason is that i don't know how do do it

Comment: Have you made any attempts yourself?

Comment: Yes... I cant seem to get it working. this is part of another code that im working on right now

Comment: @WillW presumably you've used a `for` loop before and have been shown how to lookup a value in a dictionary? You put those two together for your first step... If you show us the code that doesn't work we can probably help you with it.

Comment: result = map(dictionary.get, l)
print(list(result))

Comment: This doesnt work when the list is ['apple banana'] it just prints none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's define your variables:

```
>>> d = {'apple': '2', 'banana': '3', 'pear': '1', 'peach': '1'}
>>> x = ['banana', 'apple', 'pear', 'apple banana']
```

Now, let's compute the results:

```
>>> [sum(int(d[k]) for k in y.split()) for y in x]
[3, 2, 1, 5]
>>> sum(sum(int(d[k]) for k in y.split()) for y in x)
11
```

Or, if the first list above really needed to have strings for its elements and the sum above also needed to be string and in a list:

```
>>> [str(sum(int(d[k]) for k in y.split())) for y in x]
['3', '2', '1', '5']
>>> [str(sum(sum(int(d[k]) for k in y.split()) for y in x))]
['11']
```

Comment: This helped alot. Thanks I don't know why people are downvoting you